# how to get statuscode from aws s3 putobject response

Tags: php, aws-php-sdk

I am sending file to AWS s3 using PHP SDK. I installed SDK using

```
composer require aws/aws-sdk-php
```

I am using following code

```
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
    $s3 = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
                'region'  => AWS_REGION,
                'version' => 'latest',
                'credentials' => [
                    'key'    => AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                    'secret' => AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
                ]
            ]);

     $result = $s3->putObject([
                'Bucket'     => AWS_BUCKET,
                'Key'        => $filename,
                'SourceFile' => $fileFullPath         
                ]);
```

Following response, I am getting

[image]

I am trying to get status code from this response and tried different ways, but I could not get status code.

Answer (score 0):

You are returned an object with a private array called "data" but you are also able to just call the data by attribute. So using $result['@metadata']['statusCode'] works just fine.

`$result['@metadata']['statusCode'] == 200`

According to your example.

Answer (score 0):

Worked fine for me

```
$result['@metadata']['statusCode'] == 200
```